# Weird behavior of runuser command in cron context

Tags: linux, bash, cron

i try to run a script which contains below code, when i run the same command from root level or any other admin account level it generated the `dump` file, but if i run it as a cron-job this line seems to not work as i cant find a dump_().sql file anywhere in the system.

Cron-jobs have been created with `crontab -e` for the root account and i can see them running in the syslog

```bash
echo $(runuser -l postgresql -c 'pg_dumpall -c > dump_'${DATE}'.sql')
```

I excpect to get the dump_DATE.sql file generated

Comment: What's the point of using command substitution and echo? The output is redirected to a file, so there's nothing to echo.

Comment: Redirect stderr of the script to a file, and look for error messages there.

Comment: @Barmar so it should be just this line but without the echo?

Comment: And without the `$()`

Comment: @Barmar - already did the stderr redirection and there where no errors

Comment: This won't fix the problem.

Comment: If there's no error anywhere, it's not going to be easy to figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug a little further into the issue and found a solution.

It turns out that cron runs with a specific PATH set and as `runuser` was not in that PATH i had do modify my command to the below:

```bash
/usr/sbin/runuser -l postgresql -c 'pg_dumpall -c > dump_'${DATE}'.sql'
```

now cron-job generated the dump file